# Python Switch Text Reading Text Files

Tags: python, list, text-files, readfile

in my program i want to read txt files like "bread.txt" and in the "bread.txt" file there is just the word "True" and when its True i want that breadtext Turn's into Enabled, but if in the file "bread.txt" there is False breadtext need to turn into Disabled.
So like print ('1, ->' + breadtext)
and then `chooser = input('Enter option: ')` and when i type 1 breadtext need to turn into Enabled and in the txt file its add True but when i press 1 again its turns to Disabled and the words in the text file changes to False

Looking forward for someone that could help me :) I alreaqdy got some code

```py
    bread= open("bread.txt","r").read()
    bread1= bread.read()
    if bread == 'True':
        breadtext = '[Enabled]'
    else:
        breadtext = '[Disabled]'


    `print(Fore.CYAN + ' 1.- Bread -> ' + breadtext)
    breadoption = input(' Option : ')
    if breadoption == 'stop':
        quit()

    else:
         pass
        
    if breadoption== '1':
        if bread1 == 'True':
            os.remove("bread.txt")
            with open ("bread.txt"," w") as makebread:
                makebread.write('False')
        if bread1 == 'False':
            os.remove("bread.txt")
            with open ("bread.txt","w") as makebread:
                makebread.write('True')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: hi im adding my code right now

Comment: added my code :)